# What virtualization solution should I try next, after hitting problems w/ VMWare Player in dual-network setup?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, troubleshooting, virtualization

I have been using VMWare Player 2.5 for a while (Ubuntu guest on Vista host, 32-bit).

VMWare had worked great until now but then I hit a brick wall: Due to some reorganization of my home network, the host machine now has to use a wireless connection to reach the Internet, while the printer, fileserver, and other important stuff are attached to a local gigabit hub.

I have tried several tricks, such as editing the .vmx file, changing settings in vmnetcfg, etc, but I'm still unable to get the virtual Ubuntu box to connect each of the two virtual NICs to different networks (I did get it to recognize two NICs, but both DHCP'd onto the gigabit LAN).

So, I'm ready to dump vmware for something with a little more low-level control of network settings. Virtualization is such a crowded space, I could spend months evaluating every product out there. I'm hoping for a shortcut... Can anyone recommend the best VM for my situation described above?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

VirtualBox has improved leaps and bounds in the past ~18 months in the area of network configuration (I too recently had a similar problem when switching to wireless).  While it may not be as "low level" as your looking for, I think it's worth your time to at least try it out.

Comment: VirtualBox has fairly decent network support, I agree it is probably a good shot at fixing this problem.

Comment: It does fix the problem.  I have wifi too with Ubuntu 9.04 host for Vista guest, and it works just fine on Virtual Box.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a really "low level" solution, you could use kvm, assuming your processor supports it. There is exhaustive [documentation](http://www.nongnu.org/qemu/qemu-doc.html) for qemu, and you can take as much control as you want over the VM options.  There is also the more user friendly [libvirt][2] and its set of tools.

libvirt DOT org for info on libvirt

Answer (score 0):

I answered [your other question](https://serverfault.com/questions/79750/how-to-setup-vmware-player-on-dual-homed-2-nics-host/79852#79852)... It's not that tough to do what you want to do with vmnetcfg...